# Needs a value come first in drop down others in ascending

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, mysql2

I have a drop down list which has the following datas in products table in mysql2 database.

I am using the following model to fetch it from db

model.rb

```
def self.all_products
 product_list = product.all.map { |p| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }
end
```

products table.

```
dxx 
bxx
exx
axx
cxx
fxx.
```

I want to sort the datas in ascending order. But dxx should come in first. So that my datas could be

```
dxx
axx
bxx
cxx
exx
fxx
```

How can I implement this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One liner without any extra conditions, just pure ordering:

`product.order("FIELD(product,'dxxx') desc, product").map { |p| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }`

More about order by FIELD syntax here: http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-order-specific-field-values/

Comment: dhanakar-undefined method `order' for #<Array:0x000000074f7908>

Comment: Thank you .After removing all from the above code it works fine.This is correct code. product.order("FIELD(product,'dxxx') desc, product").map { |p| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }

Answer (score 0):

add dxx to your product_list first. then query your data in such a way that you exclude dxx in your result and ordered as ascending. finally, append that result to your product_list.

Answer (score 0):

```
product_list = product.all(:order=>"product ASC", :conditions=>"product not like 'd%'").map { |c| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }

product_list += product.all(:order=>"product ASC", :conditions=>"product like 'd%'").map { |c| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }
```

Comment: its called `wildcard` means anyword starts with "d"

Comment: ya. I tried. db sample. apple, zebra, union, cat, yield, lion, aroma, catch, dog. I want apple should come in first. others in ascending

Comment: post the result of `select * from TABLE_NAME` in question

Comment: Sorry friend. I cant add db table as it is. It is similar to the above. First letters are same. I ve changed the other letters.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather make 1 DB query and arrange the items once fetched

*(Assuming name of column is product, which has axx, bxx, cxx, dxx and so forth)*:

```
def self.all_products
  product_list = product.order("product ASC").map { |p| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }
  deleted_obj = nil
  product_list.delete_if {|p| deleted_obj = p if p[1] == 'dxx'}
  product_list.unshift(deleted_obj)
  product_list
end
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

making two db query is not that efficient, with a where condition in query will make it even worse, IMO just get back the whole list

```
    product_list = Product.all.map { |p| [p.product, p.id, {title: p.product}] }
```

then pick out the dxx item and insert it at the first

```
    idx = product_list.index{|x| x[:title] == 'dxx'}
    dxx_item = product_list.delete_at(idx)
    product_list.insert(0, dxx_item)
```

Comment: Throws this error.no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

Comment: oh, it is my fault, the line of code here x[:title] == 'dxx' should be changed to x[2][:title] == 'dxx'